# Filtering array of data where the filter text is array of strings using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, nspredicate

My array is a collection of model object whose fields are name, address, arrTags.
Here arrTags is a NSArray.

I have to filter my array based on that arrTags values.

eg. I have values like London, Paris, Australia in arrTags.

I want to display the array index ,having London in myArray if I type letter L.

So far I have done the following:

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"arrTags contains[c] %@", searchText];
  arr_searchResults =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
  [image_view reloadData];
```

This displays the array only if I type London in my search bar.
But I want to display the array if I start typing L .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `beginswith` instead of `contains`.

Comment: @IanMacDonald No Luck !!

Comment: @IanMacDonald , error pops up saying can't apply to where it is not a substring.    ( cause it's an array of tags ), so can you suggest how can I access that array index  like index[0]  or i have to enumerate that using blocks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search from inside an array (arrTaggs), you should use

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY arrTags CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText];
```

Comment: first one pops this error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object (
    London
).

Comment: 2nd one says:: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = (
    london
) rhs = l)'

Comment: Try  @"ANY arrTags contains[c] %@" and let me know the result.